# How to remove leftside scales in amcharts

Tags: amcharts

How do I remove the side scale axis in am-charts.
For eg. in this fiddle I want to remove the top scales and left scales.
what are the properties or methods that I need to manipulate.

A demo chart.
http://jsfiddle.net/JSTQW/

Currently, I am using this code for plotting the chart:

```
chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();    
chart.dataProvider = chartData1;   //data provider for chart
chart.categoryField = "year";   //this is the side category year field
chart.startDuration = 1;       //this is the chart plotting time
chart.plotAreaBorderColor = "#ffffff";  //side div rectangular border
chart.plotAreaBorderAlpha = 15;
// this single line makes the chart a bar chart
chart.rotate = true;
chart.columnWidth=0.2;
// AXES
// Category
var categoryAxis = chart.categoryAxis;
categoryAxis.gridPosition = "start";
categoryAxis.gridAlpha = 0.1;
categoryAxis.axisAlpha = 0;

// Value
var valueAxis = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
valueAxis.axisAlpha = 0;
valueAxis.gridAlpha = 0.1;
valueAxis.position = "top";
valueAxis.maximum = 100;
chart.addValueAxis(valueAxis);

// GRAPHS
// first graph
var graph1 = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
graph1.type = "column";
graph1.title = "Income";
graph1.valueField = "income";
graph1.balloonText = "Income:[[value]]";
graph1.lineAlpha = 0;
graph1.fillColors = "#7fb5b7";
graph1.fillAlphas = 1;
chart.addGraph(graph1);

// second graph
var graph2 = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
graph2.type = "column";
graph2.title = "Expenses";
graph2.valueField = "expenses";
graph2.balloonText = "Expenses:[[value]]";
graph2.lineAlpha = 0;
graph2.fillColors = "#999999";
graph2.fillAlphas = 1;
chart.addGraph(graph2);

// LEGEND
//var legend = new AmCharts.AmLegend();
// chart.addLegend(legend);

chart.creditsPosition = "top-right";

// WRITE
chart.write("chartdiv1");
```

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By setting `valueAxis.labelsEnabled` value you can get this.

Just try :

```
valueAxis.labelsEnabled = false;
```

Comment: this is not valid any more

Answer (score 16):

The accepted answer is no longer valid for amcharts4, now you can do this with:

```
valueAxis.renderer.labels.template.disabled = true;
```

And you might also want to disable the tooltip:

```
valueAxis.tooltip.disabled = true;
```